# How to join three tables that are no so related

Tags: mysql

I have three tables I want to join and hopefully, I don't confuse you.

The first table is the `exam_students` table

```
exam_students
|   id  |   student_id       | student_session_id  
|   1   |        20          |      1              
|   2   |        10          |      2              
|   3   |        21          |      3             
|   4   |        50          |      4
```

The second table is the `student_session` table

```
student_session
|   id  |   student_id  | session_id  | class_id | section_id
|   1   |        20     |      12     |    2     |    1
|   2   |        10     |      12     |    2     |    1
|   3   |        21     |      12     |    1     |    2
|   4   |        50     |      12     |    4     |    1
```

The third one is the `exam_results` table

```
exam_results
|   id  |   exam_student_id | exam_subject_id | exam
|   1   |        1          |      12         |  55
|   2   |        2          |      14         |  76
|   3   |        3          |      9          |  45
|   4   |        4          |      3          |  87
```

what I want to get is the exam score of each student (from `exam_results`) based on the `class_id`, `section_id` and `session_id` from the `student_session` table.

I'm terribly new and bad at joining. I have gone through a few articles on joining but when I see this table, I don't even know how to begin.
Please help me. How do I do this?

**UPDATE**

1. `student_session_id` is gotten from the `id` in `student_session` table
2. `exam_student_id` from the `exam_results` table is gotten from `exam_students` id

Comment: None of the `student_session_id` are in `student_session.session_id`. The rows need to be related in order to join them.

Comment: can you add the queries in your question please ?, so we might help

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Is `exam_results.exam_student_id` a FK to `exam_students.student_id` or `exam_students.id`?

Comment: At least show the expected results from the sample data.

Comment: there seems to be no way to link exam scores to specific sessions, so it would be impossible to search exam results by `class_id`, `section_id` and `session_id`. Are there more fields in these tables you are not showing? you could pull up only students that have a specific `class_id`, `section_id` and `session_id`, and show all exam scores from those students, but it would be every exam score that student has, and not scores specifically related to those `class_id`, `section_id` and `session_id`.

Comment: @dqhendricks, I made an update. But a quick one, student_session_id from the ```exam_student``` table is linked to the ```student_session``` table, and the ```exam_student_ids```  from the ```exam_results``` is from ids on the ```exam_students``` table

Comment: @Barmar, yes! ```exam_results.exam_student_id``` is linked to ```exam_students.id```

Comment: @KasimaEse right. theres a way to link exam scores to the student, and a way to link student to a session, but no way to link specific exam scores to specific sessions, unless of course there is only a 1 to 1 relationship between students and sessions, and not a one to many, as I imagine there is. if one student can have multiple sessions, and each session has multiple exam scores, ideally you would give exam scores a session_id field, so you could link exams to the session they belonged to, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join all the tables, using the foreign keys as the joining criteria in each case.

```
SELECT *
FROM exam_students AS es
JOIN student_session AS ss ON es.student_session_id = ss.id
JOIN exam_results AS er ON er.exam_student_id = es.id
```

Comment: yeah, the query is fine. But if I'm selecting from ```exam_students``` how do I get the scores?

Comment: This returns everything in all the tables, so there will be an `exam` column that contains the scores.